# How to decrease the time complexity of this O(n^3) code

Tags: java, performance, optimization, time-complexity

Here is the piece of code that's bothering me. It does the task but I want to optimize it if possible.

1. I have list of `Entities`
2. `Config` for each `Entity` based on `ID`.
3. From `Config` has `Tips` for each `Entity`
4. From `Config` has `Rejects` for each `Entity`
5. `Rejects` have `ID` for each `Tip`
6. I get `ID` of `Tip` to be `reject`, remove it from `allItems` and add it to `removeItems`

   ```
   Map<String, String> removeItems = new HashMap<>();
   Map<String, Pair<String, Config>> allItems = new HashMap<>();
   for(final Entity entity : entities) {
       final Config config = Configs
               .get(entity.getId());
       if (config == null || entity.getTxId() == null) {
           continue;
       }
       if (config.getTips() != null) {
           for (final Tip tip : config.getTips()) {
               String currentId = entity.getId();
               String currentTipId = tip.getTipId();
               if(allItems.containsKey(currentTipId)) {
                   Pair<String, Config> item = allItems.get(currentTipId);
                   if(tip.getPriority() > item.getValue().getPriority()) {
                       removeItems.put(currentTipId, item.getKey());
                       allItems.put(currentTipId, new Pair(currentId, tip));
                   } else {
                       removeItems.put(currentTipId, currentId);
                   }
               } else {
                   allItems.put(currentTipId, new Pair(currentId, tip));
               }
               List<String> rejects = tip.getRejects();
               if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(rejects)) {
                   continue;
               }
               for (String reject : rejects) {
                   Pair<String, Config> pair = allItems.get(reject);
                   if (null != pair) {
                       String rejectId = pair.getKey();
                       if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(rejectId)) {
                           removeItems.put(reject, rejectId);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you looked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com? It might be the more suitable place to post this.

Comment: Looks like this is just O(n) where n is the number of rejects.